# sql sum over with a where condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, where-clause, cumulative-sum

i have the following table in a postgresql db (it is splitted up in two tables just to show how it continues):

```
| year | month | count |
|:-----|:-----:|------:|
| 2017 |  4    |   1   |
| 2017 |  5    |   4   |
| 2017 |  6    |   2   |
.
.
.
| year | month | count | 
|:-----|:-----:|------:|
| 2018 |  11   |   9   |
```

now i need an output which is summing up all counts from the date 10-2017 til 9-2018, from 10-2018 til 9-2019 for every month.

so we start in 10-2018, then 10-2018+11-2018, 10-2018+11-2018+12-2018, ..., 10-2018+...9-2019.
and then we start the count from 10-2019 again like 10-2019 10-2019+11-2019, 10-2019+11-2019+12-2019, ..., 10-2019+...9-2020.

so the output looks like (it is splitted up in two tables just to show how it continues)::

```
| year | month | count | count_sum_ytd |
|:-----|:-----:|:-----:|--------------:|
| 2017 |  4    |   1   |       1       |
| 2017 |  5    |   4   |       5       |
| 2017 |  6    |   2   |       7       |
.
.
.
| year | month | count | count_sum_ytd |
|:-----|:-----:|:-----:|--------------:|
| 2017 |  9    |   2   |       22      |
| 2017 |  10   |   4   |       4       |
| 2017 |  11   |   3   |       7       |
```

so the counting is restart as as as an new month 10 ist coming.
otherwise we will add up all values for each month starting with the month 10.
so it is like a where condition in PARTITION BY in the SUM(count).

i have no idea how to set that condition.

thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . You can define the special group by counting the number of "10" in the month column:

```
select t.*,
       sum(count) over (partition by grp order by year, month)
from (select t.*,
             count(*) filter (where month = 10) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

You can also use arithmetic:

```
select t.*,
       sum(count) over (partition by floor( year * 100 - 10) / 100) order by year, month)
from t;
```

If you stored the date value as a proper `date` in a single column, this would be:

```
select t.*,
       sum(count) over (partition by date_trunc('year', datecol - interval '10 month') order by datecol)
from t;
```

Comment: i tried the last one. i have stored the datecol in a column like 

date 'date''
"2017-04-29"

i get the following error:
ERROR:  FEHLER:  »timestamp«-Einheit »year_date« nicht erkannt
SQL state: 22023.
for the year_date column i used this code
`DATE_PART('year',date) as year_date`

and i used this code:
`select *, sum(no_of_orders_month) over (partition by date_trunc('year_date', date - interval '10 month') order by date)`